# Large numbers, sums, and data conversions

Tags: c, char, int, type-conversion

I've been pouring over my code (which does not work) now for quite some time. It is for a Project Euler problem in which one is given a very large sum to find, and then required to print the first ten digits of said sum. (The problem can be found here: https://projecteuler.net/problem=13)

I have run several 'tests' where I add print commands to see various values at various points in the code. When I run the code, I have gotten anything from symbols to ten digit numbers that should be single digits.

Anyways. My question is this: is this a type conversion issue or is there some other glaring issue with my method that I'm missing? I've been studying type conversions trying to find a fix, but to no avail.

Thank you for any help!

The code is as follows:

```
// this is a program to find a very large sum of many very large numbers

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
//declare all ints needed
int i;
int j;
int d; // digit, need to add 48
int placesum; // sum of addition in _'s place (1's, 10's, 10000's)
int place; // final place value
int c = 0, tens = 1, otherc; // counters for start finder
int a = 0; // another counter

//declare all arrays
char numarray[101][51]; //array of strings containing all 100 numbers
char sum[100];

printf("please save data to largesumdata.txt\n\n   press enter when ready");
getchar();

// THE PROBLEM- I don't know how to get my data into my program // FIXED

// using fscanf()
    FILE *pf; // declare a pointer to the file
pf = fopen("largesumdata.txt", "r"); // trys to open file // "r" means read only
if(pf == NULL)
    printf("Unable to open file, sorry Jar\n");
else
{
    for(j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        fscanf(pf, "%s\n", &numarray[j]); // fscanf(pointer, data type, location)
}
//TESTING
//printf("You have reached point A\n");//POINT A WAS REACHED
//TESTING

//TESTING
//printf("Check1, %c\n", numarray[45][23]);
//TESTING

//TESTING
//printf("%c\n", numarray[90][22]);//Can successfully call characters from array
//TESTING

// (Brute force attempt) //I NEVER MESS WITH numarray WHY IS IT CHANGING
for(i = 49; i >= 0; i--)
{
    //printf("%d\n", d);
    for(j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {

        d = (int)numarray[j][i] - 'o';
        //printf("%d\n", d);
        //holdup// d -= 48; // ASCII conversion // could also write "d = d-48"
        //printf("%d\n", d);
        placesum += d; // could also write "placesum = placesum + d"
        //printf("%d\n", placesum);
    }

    place = placesum % 10;
    placesum = placesum / 10; // takes "10's place" digit for next column

    // now need to put 'int place' into 'char sum' 
    sum[i+5] = (char)place+'0'; // ASCII conversion // "+5" for extra space //HERE not properly stored in sum


}

//TESTING
//printf("Check2, %c\n", numarray[45][23]);
//TESTING

//TESTING
//printf("You have reached point B\n");//POINT B WAS REACHED
//TESTING

// find out where sum starts

for(c=0; c<10; c++)
    if(sum[c] != '0')
        break;

//TESTING
//printf("You have reached point C\n"); //POINT C WAS REACHED

//TESTING

otherc = 4-c;

printf("The first 10 digits of the sum of all those f***ing numbers is....\n");
printf("%d-%d-%d-%d-%d-%d-%d-%d-%d-%d", sum[otherc, otherc+1, otherc+2, otherc+3, otherc+4, otherc+5, otherc+6, otherc+7, otherc+8, otherc+9]); 

//%c-%c-%c-%c-%c-%c-%c-%c-%c-%c //copy and paste purposes
//%d-%d-%d-%d-%d-%d-%d-%d-%d-%d // ^^^^^

getchar();
return 0;

}
```

P.S. I apologize if my plethora of notes is confusing

Comment: `fscanf(pf, "%s\n", &numarray[j]);` --> `if(fscanf(pf, "%s", &numarray[j]) != 1) HandleError();`  Drop trailing `'\n'` and test result.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong form to print an array in C.

`sum[otherc, otherc+1, otherc+2, otherc+3, otherc+4, otherc+5, otherc+6, otherc+7, otherc+8, otherc+9]` -> This actually decays to `sum[otherc+9]` because C treats `,` as an operator.

To print value at each array index, you should use it like this:  `sum[otherc], sum[otherc+1], sum[otherc+2],..`

To read more about C's `,` (comma) operator, you can [begin here](http://www.mindtribe.com/2011/07/forgotten-c-the-comma-operator/)

In your `printf` as I explained above, the first format specifier `%d` gets `sum[otherc + 9]`, since `sum[otherc,...,otherc+9]` is actually a single number and that is `otherc + 9`th index of array `sum`. You do not provide anything to print for other format specifiers, hence you get garbage.

Comment: Ok ok sweet. Good stuff to know. However, while this does seem to have made it closer to correct, but when i print using both %d and %c, i still get weird answers. When I print using %d, I'm getting numbers around 40. So probably an earlier conversion issue then, yeah?

Answer (score 0):

After a while I revisited my code, and realized that I was working with numbers upwards of 10 million. I had a mix of `int`, `long int`, and `long long int` variables declared.

I re-analyzed which was which, and made sure that all variables could handle the data it needed to (after looking at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm) handy link, showing what max integer sizes are for different data types.

Before I had been using the wrong ones, and going over the max values returned incorrect values, causing my program to crash during run time.

Lesson here: Check your data types!